# Slow load nextjs (nodejs) app in apache server

Tags: debian, apache2, node.js

*Disclaimer : all the time metrics is measured via the developer tool*

### Context

I have a [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) app hosted in a vps (ovh).

The nextjs app run in port `3000` on my vps via `pm2`.

When i deploy the app in heroku (free plan) everything works fine.

In local the production build is ok too & the site takes <1s to load.

The site is served behind an apache reverse proxy.

If my vhost is configured for serving a file (`index.html` for example) and not used like a reverse proxy everything works fine.

### The problem

The problem is : when I load the site via a navigator the site takes +2min to load.

See that on heroku everything works (and on local too) I suspect my server configuration.

### Versions informations

```
➜ node -v
v10.21.0
➜ yarn -v
1.22.5
➜ pm2 -v
4.5.1
```

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

### Apache vhost configuration

#### http

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin hello@domain.dev
  ServerName domain.dev
  ServerAlias www.domain.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.dev/placeholder-pws
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.dev [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.dev
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

#### https

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerAdmin hello@domain.dev
    ServerName domain.dev
    ServerAlias www.domain.dev
    # DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.dev/placeholder-pws
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:3000/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:3000/"

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dev/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dev/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

#### check that the app is running

```
➜ netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      14383/node
➜  ps -p 14383 -o comm=
node
```

#### logs

I have 0 log in `pm2 monit` and `.pm2/logs/nextjs-error.log` is empty.

`.pm2/logs/nextjs-out.log` say

```
0|nextjs   | $ next start -p 3000
0|nextjs   | ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
```

The apache log doesn't say anything interesting.

#### post end

I have been on this problem for 3 days, any help is welcome.

If you want more informations feel free to ask.